# Setting headers and content length and mediatype in a Quarkus REST-SErvice

Tags: rest, quarkus

I'd like to migrate a JAX-RS-REST-Restservice (running under Tomcat) to Quarkus.
I could solve most of my problems along the way but I still have a problem with one method.

In this function I do a OTA-download (firmware for a device). I set some headers and the MediaType and the content length.

In the original service my code looked as follows:

```
public HomeAutomationService
{
    ...
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    ...

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Path("/v1/DownloadFirmware")
    public Response getFirmware()
    {
       ...
       response.setHeader("X-OTA-SIGNATURE", signatureString);
       response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
       response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

       return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).build();    
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find anything like a HttpServletResponse in Quarkus.
So I now use a ResponseBuilder to create a Response, where I can add headers as needed:

ResponseBuilder responseBuilder;

However, I am not sure how to instantiate the ResponseBuilder. There is a method to set headers for the ResponseBuilder, but I did not find anything on how to the content length and the content type.

I am not sure if I have to set the content-type since I already use a @Produces-annotation - but what about the content length? Is it set automatically? If no (that's what I guess) how can I set it correctly?

Thanks for reading and answering,

Rudi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use @Produces in this case and your return should be something like the code below:

```
return Response.ok(yourFileBytes[])
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, <yourFileLength>)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; ")
                .build();
```

The code above can be written as:

```
ResponseBuilder resp = Response.ok(yourFileBytes[]);
resp.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
resp.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, <yourFileLength>);
resp.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; ");

return resp.build();
```

Comment: I wrote the CONTENT_DISPOSITION header in the example just to show multiple headers.

Comment: Is there also a way conditionally add headers? I have two headers that I only set if appropriate. 
I tried your suggestion and now always add the two headers. When not needed or appropriate they are blank. However, I'd prefer to omit the headers when not needed.
How would I do that? That's why I tried with the ResponseBuilder - but unfortunately without success.

Comment: @RudolfZiegaus, I edited the answer with an alternative. Now you can add a header based on your conditions.